# How do I point programs to libraries that they require?

Tags: shared-library

I have this program that requires libbz2-1.0.so.1. I recently downloaded the libsdl1.2 library for i386 which is what the program was saying it required before. When I attempt to run the program, however, it still responds saying that it doesn't have the the other library libbz2-1.0 despite the fact that its in my /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.

```
kyle@GamingPC:~$ /home/kyle/golly/powder-89.2-lin32/powder 
/home/kyle/golly/powder-89.2-lin32/powder: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I guess I need to explicitly state where the required library is or something, which honestly seems very inefficient.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=166816) about a similar issue could help you out with the solution they used

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a 32-bit application on 64-bit Ubuntu. You will need to install the required 32-bit libraries to be able to run it. In this specific case, the `libbz2-1.0:i386` package will need to be installed.